# WebView shows HTML instead of data from local file on galaxy s4

Tags: android, android-webview

i am loading a local html file in `WebView`. It looks fine in Samsung galaxy s3 but on galaxy s4 it shows html contents. What can be done to show the data only

my code to load the url is as follows

```
webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/about.HTML");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your html files and content in your assets folder rather than in raw folder.

Then try below code, I have tested it in many more devices and it is working fine.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");
```

Hope it will help you.